# What is the use of NSExpression?

Tags: objective-c, ios, expression

How to calculate formulas like `(a + b) ^ 2, sum((a + b) / 2)` using `NSExpression`? I am the beginner to `NSExpression`.

(a + b) ^ 2 how to use whole square 2 in objective c.

Comment: The primary purpose is `NSExpression` is to remove all-caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSExpression` is not a general-purpose mathematical expression evaluator.  It's meant to be used with `NSPredicate` to describe selection criteria in Core Data queries.

Comment: simply not true. It IS general purpose, and quite extensible and although projects like DDMathParser have built decent replacements for it - it still is very strong. That Apple doesn't promote or document NSExpression abilities appropriately - does not mean it is not suitable for general purpose calculations.

Answer (score 13):

NSExpression is useful *for evaluating math expressions* in objective c.

let's see how to find the standard deviation of numbers using NSExpression

```
NSArray *arrNumbers = @[@3, @6, @3, @8, @4, @12, @9, @11];

NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"stddev:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:arrNumbers]]];

id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

It's that simple.

Below is list of functions grouped by category.

**1)List of statistics methods**

```
average:
sum:
count:
min:
max:
median:
mode:
stddev:
```

**2)Arithmetic functions**

```
add:to:
from:subtract:
multiply:by:
divide:by:
modulus:by:
abs:
sqrt:
log:
ln:
raise:toPower:
exp:
```

**3)Bounding functions**

```
ceiling:
trunc:
```

**4)Random functions**

```
random
random:
```

**5)Binary arithmetic functions**

```
bitwiseAnd:with:
bitwiseOr:with:
bitwiseXor:with:
leftshift:by:
rightshift:by:
onesComplement:
```

**6)Date functions**

```
now
```

**7)String functions**

```
lowercase:
uppercase:
```

**8)No-Op**

```
noindex:
```

Comment: Is the full syntax documented anywhere? The Apple docs for NSExpression don't really say anything about what operators (or functions) you can pass to `expressionWithFormat:`

Comment: I also couldn't find much elsewhere too..If you come across lemme know

Answer (score 9):

NSExpression is great for evaluating mathematical expressions. It is NOT only limited to core data queries and you DO NOT need additional third party libraries or write your own parser to evaluate expressions as strings.

To actually answer the question for (a + b) ^ 2 ;)

```
NSNumber *a = @4;
NSNumber *b = @4;
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"(%@ + %@)**2", a, b];
NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

Comment: Thanks god one answer got it right! NSExpression is so generic, strong and good! Its only drawbacks are the awkward and lengthy syntax for building NSExpressions, and Apples lack of proper documentation and sample-code. Otherwise, it's a rock-solid piece of software (even if a bit old). It DOES play well in NSPredicates, Core-Data and the Cocoa echo-system, but not limited to it.

Answer (score 0):

[NSExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html) is used to represent expressions in [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html). It is not intended for the tasks like yours.

Actually, you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992689/xcode-how-to-evaluate-string-formula-with-an-x-expression-inside) use `NSExpression` to calculate the formula value, but this usage is quite limited. To evaluate any mathematical expression you would need to make a string parser using some algorithm i.e. [Shunting-yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) or just reuse a library like [this one](http://www.apptree.net/parser.htm).

Comment: simply and plainly - not true. NSExpression is general purpose, not limited to building NSPredicates, and allows for arbitrarily complex expressions (with sub-expressions etc). You DO NOT need to build any string parser or string builder. You can initialise NSExpressions BOTH using their string-format, or programmatically using the NSExpression building blocks.