# Best way to convert NSString into a number

Tags: objective-c

I am building a calculator, and I have the following:

```
firstOperand = @"2883"
secondOperand = @"10"
operator = @"/" // division
```

How would I get the result here as an `NSString`? Here is how I would do the equivalent in Python:

```
result = str (float(firstOperand) / float(secondOperand))
```

How would I do the same in Obj-C?

Comment: I highly recommend looking at official documentation.  And after that, if you still can't find the answer to something so rudimentary, try searching on SO.

Comment: Also, read the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007001/what-is-the-use-of-nsexpression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have two ways to do so.
If your string only contains the number and you are certain it is "well-written" you can just use

```
int i = [yourString intValue];
```

or `floatValue`, or `doubleValue` or `integerValue` ...

If your string is not well formatted, and you need something more powerful to extract the data, you need to use `[NSNumberFormatter][1]`. For instance:

```
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber* number = [formatter numberFromString:yourString];
```

Code is ARC.

> Instances of NSNumberFormatter format the textual representation of
>   cells that contain NSNumber objects and convert textual
>   representations of numeric values into NSNumber objects. The
>   representation encompasses integers, floats, and doubles; floats and
>   doubles can be formatted to a specified decimal position.
>   NSNumberFormatter objects can also impose ranges on the numeric values
>   cells can accept.

Comment: There's also `integerValue`, `doubleValue`, `longLongValue`, and `boolValue`... but ultimately, this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Indeed. I should have guessed such question was already asked. Based on David542's reputation, I thought he would have checked first...

Comment: It's a good thought... but it appears he got all that rep via [tag:python] and has since forgotten how [so] works.