# How to use modulus operator with NSExpression?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, nsexpression

how to use modulus operator with NSExpression? If i use

```
NSExpression *exp = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"3%2"];
```

I'm getting an error — *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "3%2 == 1"'.

Can anyone explain how to correctly use modulus operator with NSExpression? An example would be great!

Answer (score 0):

NSExpression has a function feature for mathematic equations like the modulus. Here is an example of how you would perform the equation you asked:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"modulus:by:" arguments:@[[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@3], [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:@2]]];

id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", value); // Output is 1
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007001/what-is-the-use-of-nsexpression) is a link to a StackOverflow post that contains multiple lists of the functions you can use with NSExpression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+[NSExpression expressionForFunction:arguments:]`, as @Sean McDonald suggests, or if you find that too verbose, you can use the syntax for a predefined function in a format string:

```
NSExpression *exp = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"modulus:by:(3, 2)"];
```

Comment: How do you add the arguments?

Comment: You can either hard-code the arguments, as above, or use the `%@` placeholder, like `[NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"modulus:by:(%@, 2)", @3]`.