# correct use of expressionValueWithObject

Tags: cocoa, expression, swift2

I have been trying to get some basic math done with NSExpression's expressionValueWithObject(), and the results have been inconsistent.

For example, the following all work just fine:

```
NSExpression(format: "1+1").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 2)

```
NSExpression(format: "1+1.2").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 2.2)

```
NSExpression(format: "2**3").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 8)

```
NSExpression(format: "sqrt(2**3)").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 2.82...)

```
NSExpression(format: "log(2**3)").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 0.903...)

But other string-equations, seemingly no more complex than these, produce erroneous answers or no answers at all. For example,

```
NSExpression(format: "1+(1/2)").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns 1, rather than 1.5)

and

```
NSExpression(format: "43 % 2").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

(returns an error, though Swift itself can natively compute 43 Mod 2 using that same notation)

What am I doing wrong in these last two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [built-in binary operators supported by NSExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pBNF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001796-217817) are limited. `%` is not supported. Here's a possible solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061407/how-to-use-modulus-operator-with-nsexpression):

```
NSExpression(format: "modulus:by:(43,2)").expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? Float
```

`1+(1/2)` is unsurprisingly calculated with integer division. Using `1+(1/2.0)` returns 1.5.

Comment: If my inputs are coming in a string, and the input is "1+(1/2)", is there some way I can force floating point math without editing the string?

Comment: I doubt it... this seems like a misuse of NSExpression. How about parse it yourself?  :) http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/6196535272/parsing-mathematical-expressions

Comment: If I have to, I have to, but that will be a big project for me as a beginner to Swift, and the source code you link to may not help much, as I don't know Objective C. Thanks for the pointer.