# iOS - How to use NSExpression with one unknown parameter

Tags: ios, math, nsexpression

I'm using `NSExpression` to evaluate a formula in a string.

Example -

```
NSString *formula = @"7+11";
NSExpression *exp = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat: formula];
NSNumber *expResult = [exp expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

Everything works just fine but...

What if I have the following formula "7+x=18"? How can I evaluate this formula and find "x" and get the result 11?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *formula = @"12.845*x+(-0.505940)";
float x = 12.0;

NSExpression *expr = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:formula];
NSDictionary *object = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:x], @"x", nil];

float result = [[expr expressionValueWithObject:object context:nil] floatValue];
NSLog(@"%f", result);
// Output: 153.634064
```

Original Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12994596/569497)