# Add dynamic evaluation on obj-c

Tags: objective-c

I know Obj-c is a compiled language and doesn't offers any *eval* funcionality like python or ruby, but i need some dynamics functinality and i cannot decide between two different approac.

The problem:
You have a string that describe a complex math formula, like

`@"var_a + 4 - (3 * var_b)"`

I already have a way evaluate the current value from `var_a` and `var_b` so, the first step is ok.
The second step is evaluate the formula and we have at least two different options:

1. Create a string and try to evaluate with javascript engine (very bad idea).
2. Map in objects obj-c the basic idea of formula matematica. I'm talking about create at example an object  `SUM_Object` that accept two different operand and return the sum of the two parameters (and so on...like division etc).
3. Use DDMathParser.

I think the point number 2 is the best solution....any advices?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `NSExpression`?
http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/

UPDATE:

You will need something like this

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"%i + 4 - (3 * %i)", a, b];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

UPDATE2:

It is impossible to use `<, >, ==, !=, >=, <=` in NSExpression. But you could use NSPredicate

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%i > %i", a, b];
BOOL result = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil];
```

Comment: An alternative method to substitute variables is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994596/1187415. NSExpression has also some disadvantages, for example `1/3` evaluates to zero because it does integer division if both operands are integers. Actually I would use a proper math parser (like DDMathParser) for all non-trivial tasks.

Comment: Depends on formulas complexity. There is no sense to include additional third party library if all you need is `@"var_a + 4 - (3 * var_b)"`.

Comment: Do NSExpression have some boolean capability? Like `<`,`>`,`<=` et simila?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to parse/evaluate advanced math expressions have a look at [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser). It let's you also add your own expressions easily.

Example from the [Wiki](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage):

```
NSLog(@"%@", [@"1 + 2" numberByEvaluatingString]);
```

Update:

As you can see on the [Operators page](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Operators) in the wiki of the project, it supports also logic operators.